# Как правильно вставить цитату?

Tags: прямая-речь, цитирование

Как оформить цитату в следующем предложении?

1. Дык, хрен какой-то в спецовке, сантехник, что ли... он даже и не представился. «Сергея Ивановича знаешь?» - говорит.

Или так?

2. Дык, хрен какой-то в спецовке, сантехник, что ли... он даже и не представился: «Сергея Ивановича, - говорит, - знаешь?»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве **варианта:**

1. *— Дык, хрен какой-то в спецовке, сантехник, что ли... он даже и не представился. "Сергея Ивановича, **говорит**, знаешь?"*
2. Можно **попробовать** убрать кавычки, но **двоеточие** не нужно ставить, его никак не объяснишь.

— *Дык, хрен какой-то в спецовке, сантехник, что ли... он даже и не представился. Сергея Ивановича, **говорит**, знаешь?*

3. С другой сторон, здесь проблема с **вопросительным** знаком.  Для такой вставки  **кавычки все-таки НУЖНЫ.** Это  **вставка дословного** высказывания, то есть прямой речи.

**Нацкорпус**

Это пересказ чужой речи **от первого лица:**

*Может, **говорит,** я осознаю, что ты заслуживаешь большого чувства, но сейчас не знаю, что со мной. Скажи же, что нам делать? Самое главное, что я боюсь причинить боль твоей девочке. **Я, говорит, хочу, чтобы мы остались большими друзьями.** Неужели ты не можешь меня забыть? Напиши, **говорит**, обо всем. Ну и вот так.*

Comment: _"Сергея Ивановича, говорит, знаешь"?_  === А почему вопросительный знак за кавычками?

Comment: Спасибо, совершенно случайно он там.

Comment: А почему слово _говорит_ остаётся в таких случаях частью прямой речи? Я думала, раз оно играет роль вводного, указывающего на источник сообщения, то становится словами автора (того, кто говорит), если прямая речь в кавычках. Цитируемый ведь не говорил этого слова. _"Сергея Ивановича, — говорит, — знаешь?"_ Моё предположение было бы таким. Правильно ли я понимаю, что подобные предложения, оканчивающиеся знаками, отличными от точки, будут в кавычках, раз вы говорите, что проблема с вопросительным знаком?

Comment: Да нет там проблемы с вопросительным знаком, и никакой проблемы вообще нет. Это прямая речь в кавычках с упрощенным оформлением слов автора "говорит".  Вот цитата из Тургенева. - Ах! ...У него жена умерла. - Не может быть! - В сутки умерла, от холеры. Вы бы не узнали его теперь, просто на себя не похож стал. "Без Матрены Марковны, говорит, жизнь мне в тягость. Умру, ГОВОРИТ, и слава богу, говорит; не желаю, говорит, жить". Да, пропал бедняк. Источник: http://turgenev-lit.ru/turgenev/proza/zatishe-6.htm  Розенталь дает ссылку http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=158#pp158 Примечание 2(3).

Comment: А про вопросит.знак я сказала, потому что вопросительная прямая речь уж точно не может не выделяться кавычками, как было предложено в другом ответе.

Comment: Да, я видела это у Розенталя. Честно говоря, не совсем пока что понимаю, зачем у него приведены такие примеры, раз прямая речь (цитируемого другим человека) в них по итогу в кавычках (но у Розенталя примеры приведены без них), если второе примечание о том, в каких случаях не выделяется кавычками прямая речь. В примерах-то, получается, выделяется.

Answer (score 1):

Возможный вариант:

*Дык, хрен какой-то в спецовке, сантехник, что ли... он даже и не представился: Сергея Ивановича, говорит, знаешь?*

**Кавычки не нужны.**

См. **ПАС**:

> **§ 136…** Примечание. **Прямая речь не выделяется кавычками:**
> …
> б) **если в прямую речь вставлено вводное слово *говорит***, указывающее на источник сообщения: *Я, **говорит**, хочу закончить институт, профессию получить*…

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138

Comment: Представился — это что? Почему двоеточие стоит?  Объясните грамматику предложения. Это БСП?  На БСП не очень похоже.

Comment: @Sharon, лучше бы Вы объяснили **ссылками на правила** вот это из Вашего (откорректированного) ответа: _С другой сторон, здесь проблема с вопросительным знаком. **Для такой вставки кавычки все-таки НУЖНЫ**._